# curl within transaction

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mariadb

I am using google client API to fetch status of my instances to make a local database copy.

It is possible that multiple scrips update my local copy. I could fetch the data, and while the data is travelling back to my server, some other script would modify the data. After I store the data from original fetch, a lost update is created.

Therefore I need to use transactions to block all other traffic to my table while I making making an update

This is the code for fetching:

```
<?php
require_once './gcloud/vendor/autoload.php';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName('Google-ComputeSample/0.1');
$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
$client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform');

$project = 'project_id';  // TODO: Update placeholder value.
$zone = 'us-east1-b';  // TODO: Update placeholder value.
$instance = 'instance-1';  // TODO: Update placeholder value.

$mysqli = new mysqli($hn, $un, $pw, $db);
$mysqli->begin_transaction();

$listInstancesJSON = $service->instances->listInstances($project, $zone, []);

//store it

$mysqli->commit();
```

Blocking table while making a request sounds like a terrible idea.  I think I'll add `ini_set('max_execution_time', 5);` at the start of the script, just in case fetch fails (I presume they use curl). In case of execution time exceeding 5s, would my table (or database) remain blocked even after script termination? Is there any other defence mechanism I should implement?

I plan to run this code as a cron job every minute.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like `listInstances` needs the equivalent of

```
SELECT ... FOR UPDATE
```

Comment: yes, this is how I plan to store updatest. My worries are that google wont respond within 5s and potentially leave me with blocked access to table (commit never executes). What does mysql do when script is forcefully terminated and transaction is still running? Also, how much of a bad practice is what I am trying to do? I see no other way...

Comment: @arraysareslow - catch the error and `ROLLBACK` the transaction.